Can't generate native debug symbols
When running "Generate signed app bundle" in Android Studio, native debug symbols are not generated in the intermediates/merged_native_libs folder or in the app bundle. I tried not specifying the ndk version in build.gradle.kts but to no avail. Interestingly, native debug symbols do get generated in the folder above, but are still not accessible in the app bundle, when I use this implementation:
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.7.0-alpha01")

I've installed ndk(the same version as in the build.gradle.kts file down below) and cmake

build.gradle.kts:
android {
    namespace = "com.myspeechy.myspeechy"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.myspeechy.myspeechy"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 11
        versionName = "1.0.11"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "com.myspeechy.myspeechy.CustomTestRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        ksp {
            arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
        }
        resourceConfigurations.addAll(listOf("en"))
        }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = "FULL"
            }
            isShrinkResources = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
...
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
//this is the line that makes symbols generate
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.7.0-alpha01")


Did you figure out a solution to this? I am having the same problem and nothing seems to work.

@molundb, the only way i made those symbols generate is, as stated in the question, by utilizing material implementation

If  merged_native_libs  not generated mean playstore also not showing warning for upload files like armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, etc.
No Native Libraries: If your project doesn't use any native libraries (.so files), Android Studio may skip creating the merged_native_libs folder entirely.
